# Scrolling sidebar inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, sidebar

I want my social sidebar to scroll only within the gray div. I have already put the sidebar within the gray div does not exceed the footer or the content above. My difficulty is to sidebar scroll accompanying the scroll without going gray div.

```
beautyAcademy.sharer = {
element: void 0,
elementToScroll: void 0,
init:function() {
    this.element = $('.js-sharer-ref');
    console.log(this.element.length);
    if(this.element.length != 1) {
        return;
    }
    this.build();
},
build: function() {
    this.binds();
},
binds: function() {
    var _this = this;

    // FIXED SOCIAL

    // Element that's gonna scroll
    this.$elementToScroll = $('.fixed-social');

    this.$elementTop = this.$elementToScroll.offset().top;

    // Element that's gonna scroll height
    this.elementToScrollHeight = this.$elementToScroll.outerHeight();


    // JS SHARER REF

    // Element where scroll is gonna happen Height
    this.elementHeight = this.element.outerHeight();

    // Element where scroll is gonna happen distance to top
    this.elementOffsetTop = this.element.offset().top;

    // Scroll that was done on the page
    this.windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    this.elementOffsetBottom = this.elementOffsetTop + this.elementHeight - this.elementToScrollHeight;

    this.$elementToScroll.css('top', (_this.elementOffsetTop+80) + "px");

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    });
}
};
```

Comment: I cannot see the problem due to that website needing a username and password. I suggest either putting the code in your question or making a jsfiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include a minimal, complete and verifyable example. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create one. Please provide a jsfiddle or some form of code sample. As is now, your question can't be answered as we have next to no information.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/osgxcbcg/

Comment: Please note that jsfiddle does **not** support PHP. Therefore, your sample does not run.